# How can I register a nested generic type using Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector, mediatr

Using Mediatr, I have the following request handler:

```
public class GetEntityByIdRequest<TEntity> : IRequest<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    internal class Handler : IRequestHandler<GetEntityByIdRequest<TEntity>, TEntity>
    {
        public TEntity Handle(GetEntityByIdRequest<TEntity> message)
        {
            return new Session.Query<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == message.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble registering this generic request handler in my IoC. I have tried registering like:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(GetEntityByIdRequest<>));
container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(GetEntityByIdRequest<Entity>));
```

Which gives me the error:

> System.ArgumentException : The supplied type GetEntityByIdRequest<TEntity> does not implement IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>. Parameter name: serviceType

I have also looked at [this](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/69) which is identical to the issue I am having, but the person is using StructureMap as opposed to Simple Injector.

Can someone help me register my generic request handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the *query* type as a *handler*. This will obviously not work. You will have to register the handler instead:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(GetEntityByIdRequest<>.Handler));
```

Comment: Tried this and it has given me the error:

System.NotSupportedException: 'The making of conditional registrations is not supported when AllowOverridingRegistrations is set, because it is impossible for the container to detect whether the registration should replace a different registration or not. Your registration is considered conditional, because of its generic type constraints. This makes Simple Injector apply it conditionally, based on its type constraints.'

Comment: Make sure `Container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations` is `false`, as the exception states.

Comment: In order for this to work you will have to make the handler class public.